# Python : Can I global all variables in a function with a simple line?

Tags: python, global-variables

I've create a fonction in my code that need a lots of variable and constants from the program. So, I've use the `global` with my varible and it's really long : 5 lines make all variables global...

I'm scearching a new way to make easely all variables global !
Please help me

this is a perfect annoying exemple :

```
( using pygame here but not important )

def GoWindow(w):
     global screen, a, a_max, barPos, barSize, borderColor, bgBar, background, bg_loaded, current_load, a_dif, a_db, a_da, bar_percent, White, Black, Grey, Blue, Dark_Blue, Red, Dark_Red, Green, Dark_Green, Font,... #and it's continue....
     if w == 'load' #rest of the fucntion
```

Comment: if you're using this many globals then something is fundamentally wrong with your design

Comment: How about iterating over the variables with a for loop?

Comment: The correct solution here is to stop using global variables. You *probably* want to encapsulate all of those variables in a class, but it's hard to say without any context.

Comment: I am beginner at python, I use the GoWindow() custom function for any windows so for exemple when w = 'load' it show the loading window, when w = 'main', it show the main and etc, so there is all the variables for any window and I got 6 or 7 windows now ! If you know a way to make it better please help me

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the comments that there might be something wrong with the design of your program, you only need to declare `global` if you need to assign to those variables though.

```
x = 5

def print_x():
    print(x)

def assign_x():
    x = 10

def assign_global_x():
    global x
    x = 10

print_x()  # prints 5
assign_x()  # does nothing (only changes the local `x`)
print_x()  # prints 5 (the global `x` is still 5)
assign_global_x()  # assigns 10 to the global x
print_x()  # prints 10 now
```

I.e. the output is

```
5
5
10
```